Free, easy-to-use program for noncommutative algebra over finite fields
I am looking for a computer program that can handle computations in noncommutative algebra over a finite field of prime order $p$.
My requirements are:

The program should be free, as I do not have access to licensed software.

It should be as easy to use as possible, as I am not very experienced with computer programming; I have already tried using Bergman and Macaulay2, but I was unable to install or set them up successfully, likely due to my limited understanding of Linux and the associated installation processes. Therefore, I would greatly appreciate recommendations for tools that are easier to install and use, particularly on non-Linux systems.


Thank you for your time and suggestions!

SageMath these days has become quite convenient (and between the cell server, the CoCalc cloud and WSL, it is really not hard to get working), but what kind of calculations do you want to do?

@darijgrinberg Thank you very much for your answer! I want to work on the Grobner-Shirshov basis for ideals of the ring of non-commutative formal power series. However, taking power and multiplication of "truncated polynomials" would be sufficient for me now.

SageMath has functionality for (lazy) power series (see, e.g., this recent talk), though many people prefer to work with polynomials instead. You can define your own algebras by implementing recursive reduction algorithms, though I wouldn't necessarily call this easy. I don't think any methods for Gröbner-Shirshov bases have been implemented yet.

@darijgrinberg Thank you very much for your answers! I want to use very easy examples to see whether my idea about the GS-basis actually works.
